# Change size of VideoView at runtime

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-view, android-videoview, android-video-player

I have used this code to change videoview during rumtime
So, I am using this code

```
VideoView video;
DisplayMetrics dm;
dm=new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    height=dm.heightPixels;
    width=dm.widthPixels;

    video.setMinimumHeight(height);
    video.setMinimumWidth(width);
```

and on clicking of Menu item I am using this

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case SMALL:
                video.setMinimumHeight(height/2);
                video.setMinimumWidth(width/2);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Small called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case DEFAULT:
            video.setMinimumHeight(height);
            video.setMinimumWidth(width);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Default called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }   
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But Still it is not getting changed.... Can anybody help??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use video.layout(left, top, right, bottom); for your purpose.

Can you try this once.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case SMALL:
            // YOU CAN CREATE LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM FOR YOUR VIEW AND SET.
            int left = video.getLeft();
            int top = video.getTop();
            int right = left + (width / 2);
            int botton = top + (height / 2);
            video.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Small called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case DEFAULT:
                // YOU CAN CREATE LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM FOR YOUR VIEW AND SET.
            int left = video.getLeft();
            int top = video.getTop();
            int right = left + (width);
            int botton = top + (height);
            video.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Default called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }   
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I think it should work.

Comment: thnx 4 your answer....
But it is showing no effect to video... Video is laying as it is... :(

Comment: actually i have already done this you need to use video.layout(left, top, right, bottom) to change its size at runtime.

Comment: just now i edited my answer. If you can't calculate left, top, right, bottom then notify me I will calculate and update my answer.

Comment: Its working.. Thnx... But van you tell me how to calculate left, top, right, bottom??

Comment: So you should upvote mark as answer so that it will be helpfull for others. Looks like you are new to stackoverflow. :)

Comment: but selecting as a answer wont.